# How to get rid of this ? from the url

Tags: reactjs, url, url-rewriting, url-routing, react-router-dom

I'm making a react application and whenever I search for something(eg cat) on the homepage, the url changes to search/cat and the forward, backward button work normally & help me switch between the homepage and the cat search page ...but when i search for something again (eg rat) after(homepage->cat) so the url changes to search/rat? and now when i press the back button the url changes to search/rat and i'm on the same page then if i press back button again the url becomes search/cat but the page still has the results of the rat search and if i press back again ,the homepage appears..why is this happening?I think it's because of the ? that appears at the end of the url..Please help

[image]
after searching cat
[image]
after searching for rat
[image]
after pressing the back button
[image]
after pressing the back button
[image]
after pressing the back button
[image]

This is the code of the search bar

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles/searchBar.scss";
import "font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import SearchForm from "./SearchForm";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchRandomPhotos } from "../redux/actions/randomPhotoAction";
class SearchBar extends Component {
  state = {
    searchQuery: "",
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchRandomPhotos();
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ searchQuery: event.target.value });
  };

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    //event.preventDefault();
    this.props.history.push(`/search/${this.state.searchQuery}`);
  };

  handleProfile = () => {
    this.props.history.push(`/public/${this.props.photo.user.username}`);
  };

  render() {
    const { photo } = this.props;
    return !photo ? (
      <div className="search-bar-container">
        <div className="search-bar-area">
          <div className="about-foto-fab">
            <h1>Foto-Fab</h1>
            <p>The internet's source of freely-usable images.</p>
            <p>Powered by creator everywhere</p>
          </div>
          <SearchForm
            onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    ) : (
      <div
        className="search-bar-container"
        style={{ backgroundImage: `url("${photo.urls.full}")` }}
      >
        <div className="black-layer"></div>
        <div className="search-bar-area">
          <div className="about-foto-fab">
            <h1>Foto-Fab</h1>
            <p>The internet's source of freely-usable images.</p>
            <p>Powered by creator everywhere</p>
          </div>
          <SearchForm
            onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="picture-info">
          <div className="photographer">
            <p onClick={this.handleProfile}>
              <strong>Photo</strong> by {""}
              <strong>{photo.user.name}</strong>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    photo: state.randomPhotoState.photo,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchRandomPhotos })(
  withRouter(SearchBar)
);
```

This is the App.js

```js
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import LoginPage from "./pages/LoginPage";
import ProfilePage from "./pages/ProfilePage";
import SearchPage from "./pages/SearchPage";
import PublicUserProfilePage from "./pages/publicUserProfilePage";
import MobileNavigation from "./components/MobileNavigation";
import AboutPage from "./pages/AboutPage";


function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
          <Route exact path="/profile" component={ProfilePage} />
          <Route exact path="/search/:searchQuery" component={SearchPage} />
          <Route exact path="/about" component={AboutPage} />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/public/:username"
            component={PublicUserProfilePage}
          />
          <Redirect to="/" />
        </Switch>
      <MobileNavigation />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

search form component

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

export class SearchForm extends Component {
  render() {
    const { onSubmit, onChange } = this.props;
    return (
      <form className="search-form" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search free high-resolution photos"
          onChange={onChange}
        />
        <button type="submit">
          <i className="fa fa-search"></i>
        </button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchForm;
```

Comment: Need more context, please provide code

Comment: @Joshlucpoll added some code..will screenshots be helpful ? i can add them too

Comment: Yeah, that would be good, also could you add the <SearchForm/> component?

Comment: @Joshlucpoll added the component ..i'm adding screenshots too

Comment: Try replacing ```this.props.history.push(`/search/${this.state.searchQuery}`);``` with ```window.location.href = `/search/${this.state.searchQuery}`;``` and see if it makes a difference

Comment: @Joshlucpoll Its not working..there's an image with this symbol on the screen{...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles/searchBar.scss";
import "font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import SearchForm from "./SearchForm";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchRandomPhotos } from "../redux/actions/randomPhotoAction";
class SearchBar extends Component {
  state = {
    searchQuery: "",
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchRandomPhotos();
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ searchQuery: event.target.value });
  };

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.searchQuery) {
      this.props.history.push(`/search/${this.state.searchQuery}`);
    }
  };

  handleProfile = () => {
    this.props.history.push(`/public/${this.props.photo.user.username}`);
  };

  render() {
    const { photo } = this.props;
    return !photo ? (
      <div className="search-bar-container">
        <div className="search-bar-area">
          <div className="about-foto-fab">
            <h1>Foto-Fab</h1>
            <p>The internet's source of freely-usable images.</p>
            <p>Powered by creator everywhere</p>
          </div>
          <SearchForm
            onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    ) : (
      <div
        className="search-bar-container"
        style={{ backgroundImage: `url("${photo.urls.full}")` }}
      >
        <div className="black-layer"></div>
        <div className="search-bar-area">
          <div className="about-foto-fab">
            <h1>Foto-Fab</h1>
            <p>The internet's source of freely-usable images.</p>
            <p>Powered by creator everywhere</p>
          </div>
          <SearchForm
            onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="picture-info">
          <div className="photographer">
            <p onClick={this.handleProfile}>
              <strong>Photo</strong> by {""}
              <strong>{photo.user.name}</strong>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    photo: state.randomPhotoState.photo,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchRandomPhotos })(
  withRouter(SearchBar)
);
```